# How build the LLVM dragonegg on macos10.14?

Tags: llvm, gcc4.6, llvm-config

I read the book "Getting Started with LLVM Core Libraries", follow the book, I want to build a dragonegg-3.3 on my mac, so I download the dragonegg-3.3 source code form 'http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/dragonegg-3.3.src.tar.gz', and then I build the dragonegg-3.3 use command in the book

```
GCC=gcc-4.6 LLVM_CONFIG=directory_where_llvm_installed/bin/llvm-config make
```

but my mac doesn't have gcc-4.6, and I can't install gcc-4.6 on now macos10.14! , It seems the gcc-4.6 is an older version of gcc not suitable for now macos10.14.

what should I do for building or installing the dragonegg on macos10.14, thanks a lot!

Comment: dragonegg is deprecated many years ago. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer from the llvm-dev@lists.llvm.org,hope can help somebody:

```
Dragonegg is not an active project; the source is still available as a historical archive, but nobody is maintaining it, and probably nobody will answer any questions about it.
```

If you really want a system with gcc 4.6, maybe set up an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine?

-Eli

From: llvm-dev  On Behalf Of ??? via llvm-dev

Sent: Thursday, May 7, 2020 6:14 PM

To: llvm-dev@lists.llvm.org

Subject: [EXT] [llvm-dev] How build the LLVM dragonegg on macos10.14?